# How to securely send clientid and clientsecret without oauth but custom implementation with angular and dotnet

Tags: angular, rest, .net-core, jwt, authorization

I have a problem trying to figure it out for few days, still didn’t get any rigid solution.

I have an angular app which will be publicly available so no login or credential is needed to open the website, and user id is fetched from current loggedin user. The jwt token is fetched by let's say [www.mysite.com/subscribe](http://www.mysite.com/subscribe) by passing clientid and clientsecret in the body with a get verb from angular front-end.

I have a backend, that needs authentication with clientId and clientSecret, to get access_token and then call the api with access_token to post/put/delete information.

If I put clientId and clientSecret in the code a hacker can steal it and will be using it.

There were some suggestion to enable CORS on backend to make sure only requests from my site will be handled. which I already did, but with knowing the clientId and clientSecret even if CORS is enable a hacker can send requests from postaman by adding origin and referrer as header.

Front-end : angular
Backend : dotnet
We don't use oauth provider as the app is publicly internal to users

Issue: passing these clientid and clientsecret thru body of get. Which is really unsecured.

I just got into this project and I realised this unsecured implementation by previous Devs.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using OpenID Connect/OAuth 2.0's `Client Credentials Flow` for a Public Client, but it's meant to be used by Confidential Clients e.g. for the machine to machine communication, like server to server. The ClientSecret should be only used for Confidential Clients, after all, it's literally a secret, so it does not make any sense to embed it in Public Clients such as the Angular app.

You should implement another flow instead of the `Client Credentials Flow`, more suitable for the Public Client. It could be for example `Authorization Code Flow with PKCE` (preferred) or `Resource Owner Password Credentials` (the easiest to implement).